# Running ROS across multiple machine

Tags: ros, multiple, roscore, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run ROS on two machines which are connected to a local network. Both can ping each other.

I started roscore on first machine and set the `ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.22:11311` to the second machine.
When I run `rosnode list` on the second machine it shows `/rosout` node.
But when I start a node on the second machine it fails saying:

```
[ERROR] [1477518161.033462327]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying...
```

It keeps looking for ros master on the same machine. I don't know why. Both machines are running Ros Indigo.

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246532/running-ros-across-multiple-machine/) by [farhansajjad](https://answers.ros.org/users/28328/farhansajjad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-10-26

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-27**:
How did you "set the `ROS_MASTER_URI=..` exactly?

Can you add the output of `echo $ROS_MASTER_URI` (from both machines) to your question?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-27**:
Please also add the output of `echo $ROS_IP` and `echo $ROS_HOSTNAME` for both machines to your question. Use the *edit* button/link to update it.

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2016-10-27**:
Yea i think you have to use `export ROS_IP=192.168.0.22` and also the `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.22:11311` in order to be able to communicate between both machines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On each machine, you should export ROS_MASTER_URI = http:// *master_ip*:11311 and export ROS_HOSTNAME = *this_machine_ip*. For each terminal, these two environment variables should be set, so it's recomanded that you write them in .bashrc .
The former variable is used to tell this machine where the master(roscore) is. The latter variable is used  to tell master where this machine is for registering node.

*xx_ip* above should be replaced by your ip conf.Hope this answer helps.

---

Originally posted by [SilverBullet](https://answers.ros.org/users/20740/silverbullet/) with karma: 74 on 2016-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-27**:\

> export ROS_HOSTNAME = *this_machine_ip*

No. If you use `ROS_HOSTNAME`, set it to the hostname of the machine. If you want to use IPs, set `ROS_IP`.

Also: this is only needed if you don't have a working DNS (ie: can resolve all names of involved hosts to their IPs, using a DNS server or similar)

**Comment by [SilverBullet](https://answers.ros.org/users/20740/silverbullet/) on 2016-10-27**:
From your error message, I think ROS_MASTER_URI is not set correctly. Maybe you start a new window of terminal without setting variables for the new terminal?

**Comment by [SilverBullet](https://answers.ros.org/users/20740/silverbullet/) on 2016-10-27**:
Yeah, I think it's better to set ip for ROS_IP and hostname for ROS_HOSTNAME. But both can be used in practice since I've been setting ip for ROS_HOSTNAME and it has been working very well.:)